# Root of polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$

Tags: polynomials, finite-groups

I want to find the roots of the polynomial $2T^7 + 3T^6 + 6T^5 + 11T^3 + 9T + 8$ in the field $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$.

I did a polynomial division by $3T^4 + 11T^2 + 2T + 9$ which resulted in:

$(3T^4 + 11T^2 + 2T + 9)(5T^3 + T^2 + T + 6) + (5T^3 + T^2+ T + 6)$

This can be rewritten to

$(5T^3 + 3T^2 + T + 6)(3T^4 + 11T^2 + 2T +10)$

I tried to find a root for the term $(5T^3 + 3T^2 + T + 6)$ by just inserting 1 to 12 for $T$, but it was not valid in any case. 
For the term $(3T^4 + 11T^2 + 2T +10)$ I do not have any clue at all.

How can I find a root here?

Comment: Surely $T=1$ is a root of the quartic?

Comment: $T=1$ is a root of the original polynomial. Maybe long divide the original polynomial by $(T-1)$ and see how it goes from there.

Comment: How did you come ups with this factorization? Why have you divided by $3T^4+11T^2+2T+9$ and not by something else? Anyway, once you have this factorization, the roots of the original polynomial are precisely the roots of any of the two factors, you can find them just by inspection (plugging in all $13$ elements of $\mathbb Z_{13}$.

Comment: Just substitute $T=\alpha$ for each element $\alpha$ in ${\Bbb Z}_{13}$.

Comment: @W-t-P The task was to divide it by $3T^4 + 11T^2 + 2T + 9$. 
Is there a trick for checking if there are roots except for plugging everything into it? It's still manageable with only 13 elements, but still takes some time.

Comment: Over finite fields,Yyu have [Berlekamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp's_algorithm) and [Cantor-Zassenhaus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Zassenhaus_algorithm) algorithms.